# Check if parameter does NOT match regex with two possible values?

Tags: regex, bash, sh

Here is what I'm trying to do in one of my bash scripts.

If `SERVER_ENV` is not `PROD` or `TEST`, the script must exit.

```
check-server-env() {
  local SERVER_ENV="$1"
  if ! [[ "$SERVER_ENV"^^ =~ ^(TEST|PROD)$ ]]; then
    error "$(highlight "$SERVER_ENV")" " does not exist."
    echo "Exiting script..."
    echo ""
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

I call `script.sh TEST`

```
SERVER_ENV=$1

check-server-env $SERVER_ENV
```

Here is how I'm calling. And it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have ^^ before =~?

Comment: @RamanSailopal To make sure it's uppercase? I think I've tried without it as well.

Comment: The regex is not necessary. You can just do `if [ "$SERVER_ENV" != TEST ] && [ "$SERVER_ENV" != PROD ]; then ...`.

Comment: @ShaneBishop I guess it would also work. But I'd like to do it using regex. Thanks!

Comment: As pointed out by @anubhava, that's the wrong way to make a string uppercase in bash. The correct way is `"${SERVER_ENV^^}"` (note the `{` and `}`).

Comment: Wrong answer linked in dupe, voting to reopen.

Comment: @anubhava yeah, that is what I thought too.

Comment: Also I don't understand `regex` tag removal rationale. If OP wants a regex help what's wrong with having it in question?

Comment: This new linked question is also not really a dupe. *match regex with two possible values* is different from *string begins with some value* and linked question has no mention of `extglob` answer as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
check-server-env() {
  local SERVER_ENV="$1"

  if [[ ! "${SERVER_ENV^^}" =~ ^(TEST|PROD)$ ]]; then
    error "$(highlight "$SERVER_ENV")" " does not exist."
    echo "Exiting script..."
    echo ""
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

However you may ditch regex and use extglob matching in `bash`:

```sh
check-server-env() {
  local SERVER_ENV="$1"

  if [[ "${SERVER_ENV^^}" != @(TEST|PROD) ]]; then
    error "$(highlight "$SERVER_ENV")" " does not exist."
    echo "Exiting script..."
    echo ""
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex at all?

```
if [ "${SERVER_ENV^^}" != "PROD" ] && [ "${SERVER_ENV^^}" != "TEST" ]; then
    error "$(highlight "$SERVER_ENV")" " does not exist."
    echo "Exiting script..."
    echo ""
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: This condition won't match the OP's desired logic.

Comment: @ShaneBishop thanks for catching that, fixed!

Comment: Still not fixed - you need `&&`. Quoting the OP: "If SERVER_ENV is not PROD or TEST, the script must exit." Here the English language is being ambiguous, but the English "not ... or" in this case translates to `&&` in bash, because of De Morgan's law. (The English sentence translates to "not (x or y)", which De Morgan's law translates to "(not x) and (not y)").